# rsync locally filling up the disk

Tags: rsync

I want to rsync a folder locally then remotely

It appears I'm getting stuck in a loop and filling up the local server. 
The original folder is 3.9GB and I have over 17GB on the local server

All I want to do is rsync the folder locally as a backup then rsync the original folder to another backup server. I can't see where it's going wrong. Please help!

Below is the entire script;

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# check that BACKUPDIR exists
BACKUPDIR="/home/deploy/backups"
if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR ]; then
  mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR/{directories,databases,logs}
else
  :
fi
# set time variable
NOW=$(date +"%F_%H:%M") # year-month-day_hour:minute format

# set logs
LOCALLOG="$BACKUPDIR/logs/$NOW.webapps.log"
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>$LOCALLOG 2>&1
# Everything below will go to the file 'webapps.log'

# Remove files older than 7 days
find $BACKUPDIR/{directories,databases,logs} -mtime +8 -exec rm {} \;

# set directory variables
LOCALDIR="$BACKUPDIR/directories"
BKUP_SERV="deploy@server.com"
BKUP_DIR="/home/deploy/backups/$HOSTNAME/directories"
BKUP_LOG="/home/deploy/backups/$HOSTNAME/logs"
DJANGODIR="/usr/local/django"
WEBAPPSDIR="/webapps"

# set output variables
WEBAPPS_YES="SUCCESSFULL sync of webapps folder"
WEBAPPS_NO="FAILED to sync webapps folder"
RSYNC_YES="SUCCESSFULL rsync to log file"
RSYNC_NO="FAILED to rsync log file"

# check webapps or django folder to rsync
if [ ! -d "$WEBAPPSDIR" ]; then
  rsync -avh "$DJANGODIR" "$LOCALDIR"
else
  rsync -avh "$WEBAPPSDIR" "$LOCALDIR"
fi
RESULT1="$?"

# Outputs whether the rsync was successful or not
if [ "$RESULT1" != "0" ]; then
    echo -e "EXIT Code:" $RESULT1 "\n$WEBAPPS_NO"
else
    echo "$WEBAPPS_YES"
fi

# check webapps or django folder to rsync
if [ ! -d "$WEBAPPSDIR" ]; then
  rsync -azvPh "$DJANGODIR" -e ssh "$BKUP_SERV":"$BKUP_DIR"
else
  rsync -avzPh "$WEBAPPSDIR" -e ssh "$BKUP_SERV":"$BKUP_DIR"
fi
RESULT2="$?"

# Outputs whether the rsync was successful or not
if [ "$RESULT2" != "0" ]; then
    echo -e "EXIT Code:" $RESULT2 "\n$RSYNC_NO"
else
    echo "$RSYNC_YES"
fi

# Command to rsync 'webapps.log'
rsync -azvPh "$LOCALLOG" -e ssh "$BKUP_SERV":"$BKUP_LOG"
RESULT3="$?"

# Outputs whether the rsync was successful or not
if [ "$RESULT3" != "0" ]; then
    echo -e "EXIT Code:" $RESULT3 "\n$RSYNC_NO"
else
    echo "$RSYNC_YES"
fi
```

Comment: You're seeing an increase of disk space from 3.9GB to 17GB. Given you're only deleting files that are older than a week can a rapidly changing source tree account for this difference as you overlay each backup on top of the previous?

Comment: I was expecting the local backup, on first run of the script to backup 3.9GB to the backup folder. But the script just hangs and fills up the entire local disk

Comment: The script can't hang _and_ fill up the entire disk! Switch off the diversion of _stdout_ and _stderr_ and run the script with `bash -x`. See what's going on with the local `rsync` and report back here (in your question).

Answer (score 1):

Provided your variables `$DJANGODIR` and `$LOCALDIR` are valid directories and the `$BKUP_SERV` variable is a valid target host then the commands are plausible.

**You could use the `--dry-run` parameter to see what would happen.**

You should quote your variables `"$DJANGODIR"`, etc., so that spaces and other strange characters are protected from processing by the shell.

The local backup will ignore the `-z` flag and the implied `--partial` setting.

The remote backup will only be attempted if the local backup completes successfully. You should consider whether that is correct and useful. Personally I don't think I should want one backup dependent on the other, but it's not my system.

Comment: Still seems to rsync until the server if full

Comment: @eekfonky why didn't you say in the first place that the problem is you're filling up the target server? No wonder people have downvoted your question. Sigh.

Comment: No, it's the local server the that's filling up

Comment: @eekfonky same difference. The point is that you asked a question ("does this script look ok") that was completely unrelated to the issue at hand ("my backups are filling up the disk")

Comment: Thank you for the help, Sorry, I am panicking here. Didn't mean to annoy anyone

Answer (score 1):

The problem appeared to be;

```
# Remove files older than 7 days
find $BACKUPDIR/{directories,databases,logs} -mtime +8 -exec rm {} \;
```

It was missing the `-rf` after `rm`. This appeared to cause the hanging of the script.

It now works fine. Here's the full version below;

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set local directory variables
NOW=$(date +"%F_%H:%M") # year-month-day_hour:minute format
BACKUPDIR="/home/deploy/backups"
LOGDIR="$BACKUPDIR/logs"
DBDIR="$BACKUPDIR/databases"
LOGFILE="$LOGDIR/$NOW.db_bkup.log"

# check that BACKUPDIR exists
if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR ]; then
  mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR/{databases,logs}
else
  :
fi

# Set remote directory variables
BKUPSSH="deploy@server.com"
BKUPSERVDIR="/home/deploy/backups/$HOSTNAME/databases"

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>$LOGFILE 2>&1
# Everything below will go to the file 'db_bkup.log'

# DO NOT BACKUP these databases
IGNOREDB="
information_schema
performance_schema
mysql
test"

#* MySQL binaries *#
MYSQLDUMP=$(which mysqldump)
GZIP=$(which gzip)

# Remove files older than 7 days
find $DBDIR -mtime +8 -exec rm -rf {} \;

# get all database listing
DBS="$(mysql --login-path=dbbkup -Bse 'show databases')"

# start to dump database one by one
for db in $DBS
do
        DUMP="yes";
        if [ "$IGNOREDB" != "" ]; then
                for i in $IGNOREDB # Store all value of $IGNOREDB ON i
                do
                        if [ "$db" == "$i" ]; then # If result of $DBS(db) is equal to $IGNOREDB(i) then
                                DUMP="NO";         # SET value of DUMP to "no"
                                #echo "$i database is being ignored!";
                        fi
                done
        fi

        if [ "$DUMP" == "yes" ]; then # If value of DUMP is "yes" then backup database
                FILE="$DBDIR/$NOW-$db.sql.gz";
                echo "BACKING UP $db";
        $MYSQLDUMP --login-path=dbbkup --add-drop-database --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --set-gtid-purged=OFF --verbose $db | $GZIP > $FILE
        fi
done

# change permissions on files
chmod -R 755 $BACKUPDIR

# rsync backup to 'Larry' the backup server and append the log file
rsync -azvh $DBDIR/ -e ssh $BKUPSSH:$BKUPSERVDIR
RESULT="$?"

# check result of rsync db's
if [ "$RESULT" != "0" ]; then
    echo -e "rsync exit Code:" $RESULT "\nFAILED to rsync databases"
else
    echo "SUCCESSFULL rsync of databases"
fi
```